# How to download a large private file from Google Storage API with PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-client

I'm trying to allow download of large files to clients, from Google Storage API behind an authenticated PHP.

I was able to read/download small files using the following code:

```
$object = $storage->objects->get($bucket, 'filename');
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $object['mediaLink']);
//authorize the request before sending
$http = $client->authorize();
$response = $http->send($request);
$body = $response->getBody()->read($object->getSize());
```

$body will have the entire content of the file, but some of those might be 1gb size.

Tried using:

```
$stream = Psr7\stream_for($response->getBody());
```

But it doesn't work.

How would I be able to stream the download of the file to the client without loading it in memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sending the client a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs) so that the content is served directly from Google Cloud Storage, rather than trying to proxy the entire file download yourself.